# Copying part of the rows from one table to another based on certain criteria

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to transfer part of the data from one table to another. The columns in both tables are identical. I want to select rows that match certain criteria. I doing something wrong.
My query is:

```
    sql_new= """
        INSERT INTO table2 (`datetime_recieved`, `company_name`, 
            `start_date`, `end_date`, `location`,`start_time`, `end_time`, 
            `external_system_id`,`internal_system_id`) FROM table1 
            WHERE company_name ='XXX' 
            AND internal_system_id != 0 AND DATE(datetime_recieved) =DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY 
            internal_system_id"""

print(sql_new)
            cursor_new = db_connection.cursor()
            cursor_new.execute(sql_new)
            db_connection.commit()
```

EDITED :
I am now trying the code below but still getting syntax error near 'FROM table1
WHERE company_name ='XXX'

```
INSERT INTO table2 (datetime_recieved, company_name, start_date, end_date, location,start_time, end_time, external_system_id,internal_system_id) SELECT (datetime_recieved, company_name, start_date, end_date, location,start_time, end_time, external_system_id,internal_system_id) FROM table1 WHERE company_name ='XXX' AND internal_system_id != 0 AND DATE(datetime_recieved) =DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY internal_system_id
```

EDIT 2: removed the brackets after SELECT and it works.

Comment: You're missing a `SELECT` somewhere. YOU need `SELECT [columns] FROM` not just `FROM`

Comment: @Barry Carter, thank you. Do you mean sth like this:     INSERT INTO table2 (`datetime_recieved`, `company_name`, 
            `start_date`, `end_date`, `location`,`start_time`, `end_time`, 
            `external_system_id`,`internal_system_id`) SELECT * FROM table1 
            WHERE company_name ='XXX' 
            AND internal_system_id != 0 AND DATE(datetime_recieved) =DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY 
            internal_system_id"""

Comment: @user19441790, yes, INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ... will do the trick, if columns are identical.

Comment: do not `select *`, select the particular columns you need, in the same order as your table2 column list, since it will blindly use the first value for the first column, second value for the second column, etc.

Comment: @ysth thank you. The columns are identical but the id which the primary key should be different, thanks for pointing that out.